# What files to include for linking libjpeg-turbo in Visual Studio C++ 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, linker-errors, vcpkg, libjpeg-turbo

I installed the library with vcpkg: https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg

In the PowerShell (Admin):

```
.\vcpkg install libjpeg-turbo:x64-windows-static
.\vcpkg integrate install
```

I added reference to the library in :

*Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories :* [path]libjpeg-turbo-gcc\include

*Configuration Properties > Linker > General > Additional Library Directories:*[path]libjpeg-turbo-gcc\lib

*Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies* :

- libjpeg.a
- libjpeg.dll.a
- libturbojpeg.a
- libturbojpeg.dll.a

But I obtain the linking errors:

- LNK2019 : unresolved external symbol __imp___iob referenced in
  function _output_message libjpeg.a(jerror.c.obj)
- LNK2019 : unresolved external symbol _sscanf referenced in function _jinit_memory_mgr    libjpeg.a(jmemmgr.c.obj)
- LNK2019 : unresolved external symbol _sprintf referenced in function _format_message libjpeg.a(jerror.c.obj)

I tried to add the libturbojpeg.dll and libjpeg-62.dll from the libjpeg-turbo-gcc\bin folder but I obtain a link error LNK1107  invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x3D0   \libjpeg-turbo-gcc\bin\libturbojpeg.dll.

Which files do I have to include and where to find them?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `*.a` files are probably for the g++ or clang toolchain.  From the error messages you are using MSVC.

Comment: Files ending in `.a` are typically static libraries for Cygwin or MinGW encironments. For MSVC you should link with files ending in `.lib`. Unless the documentation specifies otherwise?

Comment: ok thank you. I downloaded libjpeg-turbo-gcc but I needed libjpeg-turbo64. Many thanks!

Comment: The non static build: `libjpeg-turbo:x64-windows` version in `vcpkg` worked for me a few weeks ago as I have it installed. The file names are `jpeg.lib` and `turbojpeg.lib` along with their dlls in both the debug and release folders.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't find the dll. Where is the debug and release folder?  I just have bin, classes, doc, include and lib.

Comment: You will need to create an import library for MS VC++ format. Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946322/how-to-generate-an-import-library-lib-file-from-a-dll/53838952#53838952)

Comment: Are you trying to use `vcpkg` or not? If you are perhaps there is a bug in the static build.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes I installed the library with the option static and the other time just with: .\vcpkg install libjpeg-turbo:x64-windows . It is not picked up by Visual Studio.

Comment: Then you have the libraries you need. Are you using `CMake` with visual studio or nuget or some other method for visual studio integration? You probably want to tag the question for `vcpkg`

Comment: No I don't use cmake or nuget, I tried with a simple windows console app. So I just need to add:  jpeg.lib, jpeg-static.lib, turbojpeg.lib, turbojpeg-static.lib ? Only these 4 .lib files? If I add the dlls jpeg62.dll and turbojpeg.dll I obtain LNK1104.

Comment: You don't link to `dlls` so never add these to the Additional Library Directories. The dlls should be placed in the same folder as the executable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I removed the references to libjpeg-turbo in Additional Library Directories and Additional Include Directories but Visual Studio can't find the includes.

Comment: You need to set the include paths in Visual Studio. It should not be `libjpeg-turbo-gcc\include`. It probably should be `c:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202416/discussion-between-hel-and-drescherjm).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I removed the static install to avoid any conflict. I set the include to C:\Documents\C++\lib\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include. But I still have linker issues : LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _jpeg_std_error referenced in function "private: bool __thiscall ImageData::do_read_JPEG_file(struct jpeg_decompress_struct *,char *)" (?do_read_JPEG_file@ImageData@@AAE_NPAUjpeg_decompress_struct@@PAD@Z) I also put the 2 dlls: jpeg62.dll, turbojpeg.dll where I expect the executable (project folder \ debug)

Comment: I suggest you could refer to the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48740107/link-libjpeg-turbo-in-vs-c-2017

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is what I used as a base before posting on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Please find what did work for me at the end. 
Using vcpkg:

```
.\vcpkg install libjpeg-turbo:x64-windows
.\vcpkg integrate install
```

In Visual Studio don't reference any libraries or it will lead to linker errors, only add the include to vcpkg installed libraries:

*Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories*:

```
[vcpkg path] \vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include
```